# C++ Присвоить значения из массива множеству переменных по порядку

Tags: c++, массивы

У меня 150 переменных, в которые необходимо присвоить по порядку значения из массива.

В голову лезет только это:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    
    int array[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        a = array[i];
        b = array[i];
        c = array[i];
    }
    
    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c;

    return 0;
}
```

Но результат очевиден: "3 3 3"

А хотелось бы видеть это: "1 2 3"

Как можно решить данную проблему? Подойдёт любой грамотный способ

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136535/discussion-on-question-by-aivaki-c------).

Comment: ну вот, опять. ну когда это прекратится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то я сомневаюсь, что вам на самом деле нужно столько переменных, но просили - получите:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main()
{    
    int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    auto &[a, b, c] = arr;
    std::cout << a << b << c << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Хотя, технически это не переменные...

Comment: Спасибо за хорошее решение! Надоело уже не по теме общаться с людьми

Comment: @Aivaki Чтобы с вами общались по теме, надо объяснять, что вы на самом деле пытаетесь сделать. Сейчас это выглядит как [забивание гвоздей микроскопом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/215103).

Comment: Нету желания досконально объяснять всё в мельчайших подробностях. Мне кажется, что суть моей проблемы понятна. Больше ничего и не нужно, кроме её решения :)

Comment: Да и мне слишком долго пришлось бы объяснять всё...

Comment: @Aivaki Ощущение, что вы не прочитали ссылку, которую я скинул. Я уверен, что тут есть более удобное решение, без создания 100500 переменных. Но без понимания того, что вы делаете, сложно предложить что-то толковое.

Comment: 1. Да, прочитал
2. Первая идея кажется чутка странноватой, но 100% сработает :D
3. Все эти переменные действительно нужны (большинство сейчас не используется, но в будущем могут использоваться). Мне не нужно вести контроль этого всего. Не буду же каждый раз их убирать, а потом добавлять, верно?

Comment: Я писал, что они все разом парсятся текстом со страницы в один массив. После уже есть тот же массив, но отфильтрованный регулярными выражениями - это массив DWORD'ов. Потом для понимания кода массив "разбегается" по переменным

Comment: @Aivaki Пока звучит так, что массив+енум - лучше всего. Можно не писать все 150 имен, а только нужные...

Comment: Тогда мне придётся разбираться с тем, какие нужные, а какие не нужны (и немного менять код). На это уйдёт какое-то время. Но кажется, что какая-то не очень красивая запись (array + enum), это же будет "array[something]". Можно же как-то по-другому

Comment: @Aivaki И все-таки, что за данные в этих переменных, и откуда вы их парсите?

Comment: 0x320393C - подобные данные.

Подробнее сказать не могу...

Comment: Если у вас есть ещё какие-либо варианты решения, то буду рад

Comment: @Aivaki Без понимания, что вы делаете, сложно что-то предложить. Если не можете объяснить, то других идей у меня нет.

Comment: Я без понятия, что тут ещё нужно для понимания. Всё, что дальше вопроса и вышесказанного - мои заботы, а не ваши. Но всё равно спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вариант конечно извращённый но рабочий.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ABC {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main()
{
    struct ABC set;
    int array[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    memcpy(&set, &array[0], sizeof(set));
    printf("%d %d %d\n", set.a, set.b, set.c); // out: 1 2 3
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Неплохо, но немного не то. Спасибо

Comment: Формально могут быть проблемы с выравниванием.